# How can I find compound string in text

Tags: java, regex, string, search, text

I have been searching for solution to find strings like this `howareyou` in sentence and remove them from it. For example:

We have a sentence - `Hello there, how are you?`

And compound - `how are you`
As a result I want to have this string - `Hello there, ?` With compound removed.

My current solution is splitting string into words and checking if compound contains each word, but it's not working well, because if you have other words that match that compound they will also be removed, e.g.:

If we will look for `foreseenfuture` in this string - `I have foreseen future for all of you`, then, according to my solution `for` will also be removed, because it is inside of compound.

**Code**

```
String[] words = text.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
String compound = "foreseenfuture";

int startIndex = -1;
int endIndex = -1;

for(String word : words){
  if(compound.contains(word)){
     if(startIndex == -1){
       startIndex = text.indexOf(word);
     }

     endIndex =  text.indexOf(word) + word.length() - 1;
  }
}

if(startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1){
  text = text.substring(0, startIndex) + "" + text.substring(endIndex + 1, text.length() - 1);
}
```

So, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Try [this](https://ideone.com/rbe2bu).

Comment: compound should be without spaces.

Comment: "should be" or "is" without spaces?

Comment: Is, sorry. Like in my code - `String compound = "foreseenfuture";`

Comment: What is end result after `foreseenfuture` is removed from string?

Comment: We had the string - `I have foreseen future for all of you`
Result should be - `I have for all of you`, but it also removes `for`, because it is inside of compound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that when you compound you only remove whitespace. So with this assumption "for,seen future. for seen future" would become "for,seen future. " since the comma breaks up the other compound. In this case then this should work:

```
    String example1 = "how are you?";
    String example2 = "how, are you... here?";
    String example3 = "Madam, how are you finding the accommodations?";
    String example4 = "how are you how are you how are you taco";

    String compound = "howareyou";

    StringBuilder compoundRegexBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    //This matches to a word boundary before the first word
    compoundRegexBuilder.append("\\b");

    // inserts each character into the regex
    for(int i = 0; i < compound.length(); i++) {
        compoundRegexBuilder.append(compound.charAt(i));

        // between each letter there could be any amount of whitespace
        if(i<compound.length()-1) {
            compoundRegexBuilder.append("\\s*");
        }
    }

    // Makes sure the last word isn't part of a larger word
    compoundRegexBuilder.append("\\b");

    String compoundRegex = compoundRegexBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println(compoundRegex);
    System.out.println("Example 1:\n" + example1 + "\n" + example1.replaceAll(compoundRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("\nExample 2:\n" + example2 + "\n" + example2.replaceAll(compoundRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("\nExample 3:\n" + example3 + "\n" + example3.replaceAll(compoundRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("\nExample 4:\n" + example4 + "\n"  + example4.replaceAll(compoundRegex, ""));
```

The output is as follows:

```
\bh\s*o\s*w\s*a\s*r\s*e\s*y\s*o\s*u\b
Example 1:
how are you?
?

Example 2:
how, are you... here?
how, are you... here?

Example 3:
Madam, how are you finding the accommodations?
Madam,  finding the accommodations?

Example 4:
how are you how are you how are you taco
   taco
```

You can also use this to match any other alpha-numeric compound.

Comment: Brilliant! Works awesome. Thank you so much!